# File integrity checking

Tags: checksum, data-integrity

I have a lot of PDFs and many of them may be corrupt. Rather than checking each one, how could I check them all at once and delete any that are corrupt?

Using Linux. I also don't have a way to get the md5sum of the books, so that's out.

This can either be done with a shell script or I would be interested in learning how to write a C program to do this. But again, my main problem is that I don't have anything to compare the md5sum to.

Answer (score 1):

The [Multivalent](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/) project includes a [PDF validation tool](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/pdf/Validate.html) that seems to fit your requirements.

**Validate**

Examines PDFs at a selectable level of detail and reports errors. Quickly check for invalid or damaged PDFs in your archive, or validate a freshly downloaded bunch of PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is *file format validation*. Perhaps [JHOVE - JSTOR/Harvard Object Validation Environment](http://jhove.sourceforge.net/) would be useful.